# How to convert this ObjC code to swift3?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift3

I am converting my ObjC code to Swift and stucking on this code.

```
for (id<Delegate> object in Objects)
 {

    .......
    ......

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Objective-C syntax is saying that you have a collection, called `Objects`, for which the objects conform to some protocol called `Delegate`. The syntax in Swift is the largely the same:

```
func callDelegateMethod(for objects: [Delegate]) {
    for object in objects {
        object.someDelegateMethod()
    }
}
```

Or

```
func callDelegateMethod(for objects: [Delegate]) {
    objects.forEach { object in
        object.someDelegateMethod()
    }
}
```

Note, in those examples, I broadened the example to show how `objects` was declared (i.e. as an array of objects that conform to `Delegate` protocol).

If your `objects` array was something more ambiguous, something for which the conformance to `Delegate` couldn't be determined at compile-time, (e.g. an an array of `Any`, or what have you), you might need to cast it. For example, if you know that everything in `objects` will conform to `Delegate`, you could do:

```
for object in objects as! [Delegate] {
    object.someDelegateMethod()
}
```

But, `as!` can be dangerous, as it will crash if any of those casts fail. So if there is any possibility that any of the objects might not conform, you would optionally cast, e.g.

```
for object in objects {
    if let object = object as? Delegate {
        object.someDelegateMethod()
    }
}
```

Or, writing that using functional methods like `compactMap` (previously called `flatMap` in Xcode versions prior to 9.3) and `forEach`:

```
objects.flatMap { $0 as? Delegate }  // use `compactMap` in Xcode 9.3 and later
    .forEach { object in
        object.someDelegateMethod() 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
for object in Objects {
     guard let delegateObject = object as? Delegate else {
        continue
    }
    // rest of your loop here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible options.

### Manually

Paste your code in any online converters like [Swiftify](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/).

### From XCode

```
Edit-> Convert-> To modern swift code
```

Then you will get almost exact swift 2.2 or 3 code.